# get value from edit text within a loop

Tags: android, loops, android-edittext

I have a question, as I can get all the data that has been inserted into the edit text? the edit text is on a loop, I need a way to get those   values ​​and work with them, try using an array but I get errors. could help me? any idea? Help!

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText count = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.count);
        final Button generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
        final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int numberOfControlsToGenerate = 0;

                try {
                    numberOfControlsToGenerate = Integer.parseInt(count.getText().toString().trim());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                if (numberOfControlsToGenerate > 0) {

                    if (container.getChildCount() > 0) {
                        container.removeAllViews();
                    }

                    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfControlsToGenerate; counter++) {
                        addEditText(container);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addEditText(LinearLayout container) {
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        EditText editTextToAdd = new EditText(this);
        editTextToAdd.setLayoutParams(params);
        container.addView(editTextToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, is unclear. Are you trying to get the value from the edit text, which could be a number at an instance. Based on that are you adding views?

Comment: that is the case, in my code I generate n number of EditText, what I need is to get the data that are entered there but not how.

Comment: you can get some idea from this post
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13918206/2915785

Comment: I really appreciate it! I will put into practice

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple edittext by using array.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

EditText[] sample_et; 
int numberOfControlsToGenerate = 10;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    LinearLayout root_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);

    sample_et = new EditText[numberOfControlsToGenerate];
    //numberOfControlsToGenerate is decleres statically you can get the count from edit text
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
        sample_et[i] = new EditText(this);
        root_layout.addView(sample_et[i]);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: change your for loop logic like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Add setTag when you create dynamic `EditText`

add line in `addEditText(LinearLayout container)` method

```
private void addEditText(LinearLayout container) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    EditText editTextToAdd = new EditText(this);
    editTextToAdd.setLayoutParams(params);
    editTextToAdd.setTag(editTextToAdd); //Add this Line
    container.addView(editTextToAdd);
}
```

Write code onClick listener on any Button

```
getvalue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if(container.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
                EditText et = (EditText) container.getChildAt(i).getTag();
                if(et != null) {
                    Log.i("<Tag Name>", et.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
   });
```